# How to create Modules in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

How to develop Module based application in asp.net? It means when we add a module new features will run in the application. When we delete the module it will not effect the whole application?

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely want to learn about creating a Plugin Architecture.

There's some [information here on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/PluginManagerClassBrk.aspx) on how to Create a flexible & dynamic plugin architecture.

[This question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433561/plugin-architecture) will also give you some fantastic information.